# selenium python Ajax-подгрузка

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Как мне перехватить событие ajax-подгрузки на selenium? Предположим, что есть сайт со списком статей, при скроллинге вниз посылается запрос на сервер и запускается подгрузка более поздних статей (типо ленты ВК), я не хочу костылить всякими time.sleep(), а хочу перехватывать событие подгрузки нового контента и этот новый контент уже парсить к себе в базу. Есть у selenium-а какая-нибудь фича удобная для этого?

Comment: Прям такой фичи нет. Можно использовать `driver.execute_script`, чтоб исполнить js код, который будет [слушать события](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) dom и ждать нужное. sleep использовать это, конечно, неправильно, лучше ждать пока появится элемент использую явное или неявное ожидание

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA не плохо, думаю то что нужно, да.

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA этот скрипт может что то возвращать потом в питон мне? Типо True/False?

Comment: да, в конце пишете `return True;` смотрите доку https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script

Comment: А адресная строка меняется при скроллинге вниз?

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/

Comment: @Сергей Шашко Нет, не меняется. Вы немного не поняли проблему. У меня нет проблемы в том чтобы сделать скролл через селениум.

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA вы очень помогли мне, можете скопировать ваш комментарий в ответ и я с удовольствием приму его.